# Docker container not connecting mongodb host

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

I'm facing MongoDB connection issue from docker container, i read few stackoverflow answers but not helped me to solve my issue.

My application.yml file has the following,

```
spring:
   application:
    name: web-ui-service
   data:
     mongodb:
       uri: mongodb://<username>:<pwd>@172.17.0.1:27017/database
```

and My docker-compose file has the following,

version: '3.5'
    services:

```
sp-app-web-ui:
  container_name: sp-app-web-ui
  image: swimming-pool/web-ui-service
    environment:
    - DOCKER_HOST_IP=mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017
     - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=swimming-pool
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
   networks:
     - swimming-pool-app
       restart: unless-stopped

     networks:
       swimming-pool-app:
     default:
       driver: bridge
```

I read this blog [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

but still am facing the following issue,

sp-app-web-ui    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
sp-app-web-ui    |      at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
sp-app-web-ui    |      at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]

I'm using Debian and Docker 18.06. It would be great if you anyone help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the question, my docker-compose file looks as  below,

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  sp-app-web-ui:
  container_name: sp-app-web-ui
  image: swimming-pool/web-ui-service
  environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  network_mode: host
```

and add "127.0.0.1" in mongo.conf file in the bindIp variable.

My application.yml has the following,

```
spring:
   application:
    name: web-ui-service
    data:
     mongodb:
       uri: mongodb://<username>:<pwd>@172.0.0.1:27017/database
```

This IP 127.0.0.1 got it from docker0 when you ping ip a on linux.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is to add `network_mode: "host"` to your docker compose service:

```
sp-app-web-ui:
  container_name: sp-app-web-ui
  image: swimming-pool/web-ui-service
    environment:
    - DOCKER_HOST_IP=mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017
     - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=swimming-pool
   ports:
     - 8080:8080

   # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode
   network_mode: "host"
```

You can read more about in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, i tried to used it but gives me an docker ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined
I changed driver bridge to host also but not connecting.

Comment: My mongo.conf file has

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1,0.0.0.0

Comment: Still the same issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the docker-compose.yml below. Then run mongodb and mongo-express (UI to access mongodb)

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```